# CSS transparency works only on Mozilla

Tags: css

I want to make a box content that is transparent and when you mouseover it is the normal image. It works super with Mozilla with opacity, but when I added other stuff so it would work on other browsers, nothing works.

```css
.BoxPage a {
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
  /* ...but not required as filter works too */
  /* should come BEFORE filter */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
  /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  /* Modern!
     /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
     /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
  opacity: 0.6!important;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=60)”;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.6;
}

.BoxPage a:hover {
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100%;
  /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
  /* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
  /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
  /* ...but not required as filter works too */
  /* should come BEFORE filter */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
  /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  /* Modern!
     /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
     /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
  opacity: 1!important;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=100)”;
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="BoxPage"><a>some text</a></div>
```

And still the transparency works only on Mozilla.

Comment: As the comments in your CSS show, prefixed opacity has not been needed in many, many years. You can remove all of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
element {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}

element:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
    
.box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hover over the space below...</h2>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the "regular" `opacity` last in your CSS rules, *after*  all the prefix-versions.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 0 100px 100px 100px;
  background: #fff;
  
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity: 0.6;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=60)”;
  -webkit-opacity: 0.6;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.inner:hover {
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  -khtml-opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=100)”;
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rgba` for color background so you can add `opacity` instead of using `opacity` property in `css`. See code below.

```css
   
*{ box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
 .box-wrap 

{ 
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px; 
 position: relative;
 background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaPw.png); 
}
.box
{ 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
margin: 0 auto; 
color: #fff; 
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
left: 0;
}

.box:hover
{ 
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* last value 0.5 represents opacity, first three numbers represents color value. */
transition: 0.5s ease; 
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease; 
}
```

```html
   
 <div class="box-wrap"><div class="box">Hover me!</div></div>
```